# Looking for original version of 'Grocer Jack' online

Tags: release

I'm looking for a version of the song, *Grocer Jack* online. It's sometimes subtitled *Extract From a Teenage Opera*, and by Mark Wirtz. It's been covered a few times, but I want the original, with children singing the song. I've found various items on YouTube that purport to be what I'm looking for, but aren't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I didn't understand your question, but the first result on youtube gave me this :

[Keith West - *Excerpt from a Teenage Opera* (1967)](https://youtu.be/ENblHOxi1c4)

Children start singing at [1:43](https://youtu.be/ENblHOxi1c4?t=103).

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excerpt_from_A_Teenage_Opera):

> *Excerpt from A Teenage Opera* (also known as *Grocer Jack*) is a 1967 single by Keith West, produced by **Mark Wirtz**.

---

Alternative links: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aEIiJyHaoBA), [Dailymotion1](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x6v212_keith-west-grocer-jack_music), [Dailymotion2](http://www.dailymotion.com/video/x3gkxd0_grocer-jack-keith-west_music).

Comment: That's the one, the original - the 'teenage opera' was completely fictitious.

Comment: Actually, @Tetsujin, there was a [*A Teenage Opera*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A_Teenage_Opera) album  and *Grocer Jack* was one of its singles.

Comment: Interesting - though strictly, it never did exist except in Wirtz's head. The album didn't actually see the light of day until the 90s. Would be interesting to hear it, though... might have to see if I can find a copy

Comment: Thanks, but when I click on that link, I get 
"This video contains content from WMG, who has blocked it in your country on copyright grounds.
Sorry about that."

Comment: @Bebs, Thanks again, but I get the same with that one. I'm in the USA.

Comment: @Bebs: Thank you very much! The DailyMotion links both work for me. I remember being very moved when I first heard children singing "Grocer Jack, Grocer Jack, Is it true what Mummy says, 'You won't come back, oh no, no'?", although I'm surprised that it was as late as 1967.